# bs4 `next_sibling` VS `find_next_sibling`

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I struggling with usage of `next_sibling` (and similarly with `next_element`). If used as attributes I don't get anything back but if used as `find_next_sibling` (or `find_next`) then it works.
From the [doc](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#next-sibling-and-previous-sibling):

- `find_next_sibling`: *"Iterate over the rest of an element’s siblings in the tree. [...] returns the first one (of the match)"*
- `find_next`: *"These methods use .next_elements to iterate over [...] and returns the first one"*

So, `find_next_sibling` depends on `next_siblings`. On what does `next_sibling` depends on and why do they return nothing?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<div class="......>
 <div class="one-ad-desc">
  <div class="one-ad-title">
   <a class="one-ad-link" href="www this is the URL!">
    <h5>
     Text needed
    </h5>
   </a>
  </div>
  <div class="one-ad-desc">
    ...and some more needed text here!
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

for div in soup.find_all('div', class_="one-ad-title"):
    print('-> ', div.next_element)
    print('-> ', div.next_sibling)
    print('-> ', div.find_next_sibling())-> ')
    break
```

Output

```
->  

->  

->  <div class="one-ad-desc">
    ...and some more needed text here!
  </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main point here in my opinion is that `.find_next_sibling()` scope is on **next level** on the tree.

While `.next_element` and `.next_sibling` scope is on the **same level** of the parse tree.

So take a look and print the name of the elements and you will see next element is not a tag, cause there is nothing on same level of the tree :

```
for div in soup.find_all('div', class_="one-ad-title"):
    print('-> ', div.next_element.name)
    print('-> ', div.next_sibling.name)
    print('-> ', div.find_next_sibling().name)

#output
->  None
->  None
->  div
```

So if you change your input to one line and **no spaces,...** between tags you got the following result:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<div class="......><div class="one-ad-desc"><div class="one-ad-title"><a class="one-ad-link" href="www this is the URL!"><h5>Text needed</h5></a></div><div class="one-ad-desc">...and some more needed text here!</div></div></div>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

for div in soup.find_all('div', class_="one-ad-title"):
    print('-> ', div.next_element)
    print('-> ', div.next_sibling)
    print('-> ', div.find_next_sibling())
```

Output:

```
->  <a class="one-ad-link" href="www this is the URL!"><h5>Text needed</h5></a>
->  <div class="one-ad-desc">...and some more needed text here!</div>
->  <div class="one-ad-desc">...and some more needed text here!</div>
```

---

**Note** *"text needed" is not in a sibling of your selected tag, it is in one of its children. To select "text needed" -> `print('-> ', div.find_next().text)`*

Comment: Hi! That's make sense! Mmm why does the `\n` character do such interference? That code I took it from a "`bs4.prettified`" page. Does it means I cannot relay on `prettify()`?

Comment: You can relay but you have to use `div.find_next()` for next child or `div.find_next_sibling()` for next sibling cause they focus on tag/tree structure.