# Python BeautifulSoup issue in extracting direct text in a given html tag

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, text-extraction

I am trying to extract direct text in a given HTML tag. Simply, for `<p> Hello! </p>`, the direct text is `Hello!`. The code works well except with the case below.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup('<div> <i> </i> FF Services </div>', "html.parser")
for tag in soup.find_all():
    direct_text = tag.find(string=True, recursive=False)
    print(tag, ':', direct_text)
```

Output:

```
`<div> <i> </i> FF Services </div> :  `
`<i> </i> :  `
```

The first printed output should be `<div> <i> </i> FF Services </div> : FF Services` , but it skips `FF Services`. I found that when I delete `<i> </i>` the code works fine.

What's the problem here?

Comment: but my HTMLs do not always contain <div>. why `stripped_strings`?

Comment: I removed the white space between the tags and works! Check it with `'<div><i> </i> FF Services </div>'`

Comment: With my previous comment I meant that `find` shouldn't be used to extract text but to find node(s) of the tree. To extract the text use `strings`, `stripped_strings`,...

Comment: @cards , it returns `None` for me. `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup('<div><i> </i> FF Services </div>', "html.parser")
for tag in soup.find_all():
    print(tag, ':', tag.string)`

Comment: on version `4.11.1` that white space make the difference:) So, without it outputs `<div><i> </i> FF Services </div> :  FF Services 
<i> </i> :  `

Comment: I have `beautifulsoup4==4.11.2` version! could you post your code as an answer? I am confused now.

Comment: I tried also with two online compiler running [4.12.0](https://www.sololearn.com/compiler-playground/cvdvAGGqi8g5/) and [4.11.1](https://paiza.io/projects/Pih2ZBgIZyQ4d4plcA6ApA) and the whitespace produce different behaviors,

Comment: same for [4.10](https://onlinegdb.com/gXYF0XwiU)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `.find_all` instead of `.find` will give the desired output. Try this code.

```
for tag in soup.find_all():
    direct_text = tag.find_all(string=True, recursive=False)
    print(tag, ':', direct_text)
```

Comment: if I use `.text`, I get the text of everything, even from children.

Comment: Had updated the code.

Comment: Also, `.find_all` will give text as list which also considered whitespaces between tags. To get only the text, use `''.join(tag.find_all(string=True, recursive=False)).strip()`.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is not of `BeautifulSoup` methods. Also your code works... you just fall in your own trap!*^1* `div.find(string=True)` get the 1st match of a **node** containing a string and when it parses`<div> <i>...` there is for sure `<i>` but before it there is also a `NavigableString` which consists of a single white space. This means that in your code there is actually a single white space printed. Here a test:

```
print(f"{len(soup.div.find(string=True)) = }") # using same soup as in the question
#len(soup.div.find(string=True)) = 1
```

It is helpful to look at the tag's content:

```
for tag in soup.div.contents:
    print(f"-{tag}-", type(tag))

#- - <class 'bs4.element.NavigableString'>
#-<i> </i>- <class 'bs4.element.Tag'>
#- FF Services - <class 'bs4.element.NavigableString'>
```

Be aware that, from the [doc](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#string),:
*"If a tag contains more than one thing, then it’s not clear what .string should refer to, so .string is defined to be None:"*. To bypass this either use better navigation instructions if possible or use `strings`, `stripped_strings` together with some parsing.

---

*^1* it happened also to me smt [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71616816/bs4-next-sibling-vs-find-next-sibling)